Quantifier over Disjunction & Implication
The following logical statement is clearly false:
$$(P \implies Q \lor R) \implies ((P \implies Q) \lor (P \implies R)).$$
For instance, the following statement can be trivially shown to be false:
$$\forall A \forall B \forall S\quad \Big(\forall x(x\in S \implies (x \in A) \lor (x \in B)) \implies (\forall x(x\in S \implies x \in A) \lor \forall x(x \in S \implies x \in B))\Big).$$
However, we have
$$(P \implies Q \lor R) \\\implies (\neg P \lor (Q \lor R)) \\\implies ((\neg P \lor \neg P) \lor (Q \lor R)) \\\implies ((\neg P \lor Q) \lor (\neg P \lor R)) \\\implies ((P \implies Q) \lor (P \implies R)).$$
What am I doing wrong?

The first statement is true (at least in classical propositional logic), and consequently so is the second statement. What would not be true is if you distributed the $\forall x$ quantifier over the disjunction, as in $(\forall x. x\in S \to x \in A \cup B) \to (\forall x. x \in S \to x \in A) \lor (\forall x. x \in S \to x \in B)$.

Why is that? Could you elaborate in an answer?

You have to consider the correct "position of the quantifier in order to apply the above propositional law... It requires the form $P \to (Q \lor R)$ but $\forall x (x \in S \to x \in A \cup B)$ is $\forall x (x \in S \to (x \in A \lor x \in B))$ and this is NOT the same as $\forall x (x \in S) \to (\forall x (x \in A) \lor \forall x (x \in B))$

All your three sentences are logically valid. A pertinent explanation is at the sister/parallel page Why is ((p∧q)⇒z)⇒(p⇒z)∨(q⇒z) true?.

Thank You, Ryang and Mauro!

The first statement is true in classical propositional logic, and you gave a valid proof of it.
Consequently, the second statement (fixing sets $A$, $B$ and $S$)
$$\forall x. (x \in S \to x \in A \lor x \in B) \to (x \in S \to x \in A) \lor (x \in S \to x \in B)$$
is also true: for every fixed $x$, either $x \in A$ and the first disjunct holds, $x \in B$ and the second disjunct holds, or $\neg (x \in A \lor x \in B)$, in which case $x \notin S$ and hence both disjuncts hold vacuously.
The statement remains true if you distribute the quantifier $\forall x$ over the implication, as in
$$(\forall x. x \in S \to x \in A \lor x \in B) \to \forall x. (x \in S \to x \in A) \lor (x \in S \to x \in B)$$
However, the statement becomes false if you distribute the $\forall x$ over the disjunction, as in
$$(\forall x. x \in S \to x \in A \lor x \in B) \to (\forall x. x \in S \to x \in A) \lor (\forall x. x \in S \to x \in B)$$
or in short
$$ S \subseteq A \cup B \to S \subseteq A \lor S \subseteq B$$
This, I suspect, is what you had in mind when you claimed that the first statement above was false. Indeed, it's easy to falsify this by taking $S = A \cup B$: the premise holds trivially, but the conclusion implies that $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$, which isn't true in general.
More generally, the following is not true:
$$ (\forall x. P(x) \lor Q(x)) \to (\forall x. P(x)) \lor (\forall x. Q(x)) $$
As a simple counterexample, consider $P(n) = n\text{ is even}$, $Q(n) = n\text{ is odd}$ over the natural numbers.
